# Laravel 5.2 Authentication ~ Routes Based On Authentication State

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to do something that I believe to be simple, I'm just having some trouble along the way. My code below includes my `routes.php` and my `verify.php` that authenticates a user. Basically, I want the routing to the homepage to change based on if the user is authenticated or not.

So first, I have the controller (`verify.php`)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Email;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Google_Client; 
use Auth;
use App\User;
class verify extends Controller
{

public function verifyIdToken(Request $request)
  {
$user = User::where('name', 'Molly')->first();
    Auth::login($user);
    return;
}
  }
```

This script is hit in an ajax request when the user first satisfies some conditions to be logged in, but that is client-side logic and not important at this point. The idea is that once the script is hit, the user is logged in.

To add more detail:

The header of my `routes.php` is this:

```
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Is there something I am missing?

My routes.php logic is now this:

```
if (Auth::guest()) {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
} else {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('mainview');
    });
}
```

But it still doesn't work, even though in `verify.php` I have added in the following confirmation:

```
if (Auth::check($user))
{
    return view('aviewII')->with(['verify' => json_encode("Yes!")]);
}
```

Which I am getting returned in my ajax requests.

So even though that tells me I am authenticated, I still can't get the authenticated view. What should I try next?

Edit: My `routes.php` in its entirety:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
use App\punsmodel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

if (Auth::guest()) {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
} else {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
       return view('mainview');
    });

     Route::get('mainview', function ()    {
       return view('mainviewMolly');
    });
});
}

Route::get('puns', function () {
    return view('puns');
});

Route::post('google' ,  [
    'as' => 'verify.index',
    'uses' => 'verify@verifyIdToken'
]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```

Comment: Can you post all of your **routes.php** file? Seems there’s something else going on.

Comment: As I expected. The problem is, you’re home page routes don’t have any middleware applied, so if you check if a user is authenticated it will always return `false`. See my updated answer for how to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d just have a conditional in **routes.php**:

```
if (Auth::guest()) {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home.logged_out');
    });
} else {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home.logged_in');
    });
}
```

Also, a couple of styling tips:

- Classes should have “StudlyCased” names, so `class verify` should be `class Verify`.
- Order your `use` statements alphabetically, makes scanning much easier ;)

**UPDATE:**

If you want to check the authentication status of a user, you need to make sure those routes are *inside* the group with middleware applied:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return view('home.logged_out');
    } else {
        return view('home.logged_in');
    }
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't appear to be working... do I have to refresh something after modifying the `routes.php`? Also thanks for the tips!

Comment: Btw, I used `Auth::check($user)` and confirmed the user was authenticated, but still nothing.

Comment: Yes, you’ll need to refresh if you haven’t already. If you have, we need more to go on that ‘not working’.

Comment: I didn't mean refresh the page, I meant something like resetting a file through the command line. In terms of not working, I simply keep getting the `home.logged_out` view, even after checking and confirming I am authenticated

Comment: No. It’s just a simple conditional.

Comment: Added more details to my question in the hopes I can provide you more information to fix the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you're on L5.2, this is a bit different. Check [this article](http://andrew.cool/blog/64/How-to-use-API-tokens-for-authentication-in-Laravel-5-2).

From what I got, you have to add an `api_token` field to your users table. Then when you want to check if a User is logged in, you can do this `Auth::guard('api')->check()`.

When you log your user, you have to return the api_token in your response and add this field to any of your Ajax requests.

Hope that helped ;)

Comment: Can you show me how this would look in the context of my code? I tried implementing this based on the article but it didn't appear to work, probably because the snippets are out of context. Thank you! :)

Comment: Sorry but I've never used L5.2 right now, I can't put some code here without testing it... Since L5.2 and its Auth system is pretty new, there's not much tuto at this time, so I would suggest you to use L5.1 instead. There's a lot of videos and example on this one.

Comment: I'm doing to do a fresh install of L5.1 then and try that way, but I will keep this question up for a potential solution to the L5.2 issue. :)